# c++ comparing two file and remove the duplicate common number

Tags: c++

t try to write a c++ program , that take two files contains a random number , and i compare both file ( each number from file1 with all number from file2 )

```
//open and read the two file "rno1.txt" and "rno2.txt".
     ifstream inputfile1;
     inputfile1.open("rno1.txt");
     ifstream inputfile2;
     inputfile2.open("rno2.txt");

     bool found = false;
     bool F = false;

     int CList1[20]; //save the containt of file1.
     int CList2[20]; //save the containt of file2.
     int i=0,j=0;
     int n1,n2;


     //move the containt of file1 to the array.
     while ( inputfile1 >> n1  && i < 20 )
     {
         CList1[i]= n1;
         i++;
      }

     //move the containt of file2 to the array.
     while ( inputfile2 >> n2  && j < 20 )
     {
         CList2[j]= n2;
         j++;
      }
     inputfile2.close();

     //comparing the common number between both files.
     for ( int x=0 ; x<20 ; x++ )
     {
               for ( int y=0 ; y<20 ; y++ )
               {
                    if ( CList1[x] == CList2[y] )
                    { cout <<  CList1[x] << "\n" ;
                      found = true; }
               }
      }


     //checking if there is common numbers between both files or not!
     if ( found == false )
     { cout << "There are NO common number!" << "\n"; }

     inputfile1.close();
     inputfile2.close();
```

**The problem :**

I want to remove the duplicate common number between both files before the print for common number ..

for example :

```
file1     file2
  2         4
  3         2
  2         4
  4         0
  4         3
  1         7
```

the common number will be:

```
2
3
2
4
4
4
4
```

the result that i want is :

```
2
3
4
```

Comment: @user3528438 how can i use it ?

Comment: @PaulKienitz what :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Take all the numbers from both lists, dump them in an array.
- Sort the array
- Step the array and only print out the number if there's more than one of it.

Comment: which sort should i use ?

Comment: You can just use the default array sort. 


std::sort(myvector.begin(), myvector.end())

Comment: and if i add all number from both files , how i will know which numbers are the common between them ?

Comment: @ZahooriNazo as you step through the array, you can count how many times a number has been seen. Reset the count when there's a new number.